# Delaying Setinterval function

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to delay when the first picture is clicked because it is firing off before it enters the screen maybe I need to put it in an if else statement?

```
// Instagram hacks

//  Search field
// let Searchtest= prompt("Please enter the hashtag you want to like","Trending");

// var search = document.querySelector('.x3qfX').value = "#" + Searchtest;

document.querySelector(".glyphsSpriteSafari__outline__24__grey_9").click();
let firstPicture = document.querySelector("div._9AhH0");
firstPicture.click();
let likesGiven = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  let heart = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9"
    ),
    arrow = document.querySelector(".coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow");

  if (heart[1]) {
    heart = heart[1].parentElement;
    likesGiven++, heart.click();
  }
  arrow.click();
  console.log(`You've liked ${likesGiven} post(s)!`);
}, 2000);

// Button Liker

My Last Attempt Run this in your console from instagrams homepage and you u will see what
```

i mean

```
document.querySelector(".glyphsSpriteSafari__outline__24__grey_9").click();
    let firstPicture = document.querySelector("div._9AhH0");
    if (firstPicture){
        firstPicture.click();

    }
```

Comment: I cant put the code in my browser just searches google please take your downvote back

Comment: Can you explain the issue a little more in depth, and how are you calling this code. Is it just allowed to run as soon as this js file is loaded, are you using a document.onReady or body.onLoad event to trigger it?

Comment: Hey i am inputing this into the console to perform tasks so it clickes the explore page and then is supposed to click the first image on the page but it is clicking too quickly.

Comment: Got it, I have an idea...

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is it: maybe you should wait for the document to get loaded, seems like you can do it with  DOMContentLoaded evenListener and then in the onready callback you can execute your click function : See below example

DOM has not changed in ES6, ES6 gives new features to JavaScript, that is all. In pure js exists event for dom loaded  it is document ready from jquery equivalent

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){ //do something here });
```

Modules working with DOM tree can have listener inside, or should be used after dom is ready. I created example DOM function to show what I mean:

```
var DOM=function(selector){

 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{

 this.element=document.querySelector(selector);

 if (typeof this.callback === 'function')
 this.callback();

});

};

//HERE WE HAVE CALLBACK WHEN OUR MODULE CAN BE USED
DOM.prototype.onReady=function(callback){

 this.callback=callback;

};

DOM.prototype.getElement=function(){
//example object method

return this.element;

};

DOM.prototype.click=function(){

return this.element.click

};
```

Usage example:

```
document.querySelector(".glyphsSpriteSafari__outline__24__grey_9").click();
var d=new DOM("div._9AhH0");
firstPicture.onReady(()=>{

firstPicture.click();

});
//your other code
```

Modules should be DOM independent, creating modules which are exporting DOM elements directly are very wrong practice. So it can be done in two ways:

Modules should get selectors DOM object in attributes and should be called after DOM is ready. So Your module has no idea where is called, but it needs ready DOM structure. In this situation DOM ready callback is only in main file which is using modules and call them.

Modules can have some DOM ready listeners but also We need some information when module can be used ( this situation I showed in example and onReady function).

Comment: Thank you i tried this and the it is still firing too early :(

Comment: maybe you should make sure that you are not clicking before dom is loaded

Answer (score 1):

You might try a while loop that sleeps for a little bit and then checks to see if your required element has appeared in the dom.

Add this sleep function.

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Now put this bit of code at the start of your method where firstPicture isn't found. This will make the script wait a 10th of a second if it doesn't find the element and then tries it again. Once it finds the element, your code continues as expected.

```
while( null == document.querySelector("div._9AhH0") ) {
  sleep( 100 );
}
```